# How can I convert a color string to a color object?

Tags: c#, bitmap

```
string color = @"Color [A=255, R=245, G=243, B=244]";
Color pixelColor = bitmap.GetPixel(x, y);
Color newColor = Color.FromArgb(color);
bitmap.SetPixel(x, y, newColor);
```

How do I convert the color string so I can use it as a Color object?

Answer (score 3):

The `Color` class can only create a custom color object in two ways:

- Using one of the well-known color names (either as a string or via the `KnownColor` enumerations) representing a Windows theme element or system color
- Using the integer values for the components.

Anything else and you will need to parse the data yourself and extract the A, R, G, and B components of the color. In your case, you would probably want to extract what is inside the `[]`, split them on `,`, then use `Int32.Parse()` to read the individual values. Assuming the string always takes the same format, something like this:

```
var elements = color.Substring(7, color.Length - 8)
    .Split(',')
    .Select(x => x.Split('='))
    .ToDictionary(x => x[0].Trim(), x => x[1].Trim());

var components = new int[] 
{
   int.Parse(elements["A"]),
   int.Parse(elements["R"]),
   int.Parse(elements["G"]),
   int.Parse(elements["B"])
};

var newColor = Color.FromArgb(components[0], components[1], components[2], components[3]);
```

With, of course, proper error checking and such.

Answer (score 2):

Agree with @Michael Edenfield, just suggest a small improvements to his code:

```
var elements = color.Substring(7, color.Length - 8)
            .Split(',')
            .Select(x => x.Split('='))
            .ToDictionary(x => x[0].Trim(), x => int.Parse(x[1]));

var newColor = Color.FromArgb(elements["A"], elements["R"], elements["G"], elements["B"]);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`String.Substring`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aka44szs.aspx) and [`String.IndexOf`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kwb0bwyd.aspx) methods to extract your information also. It will work as long as your data is in a somewhat predicable format.

```
char[] trimChars = new char[] { ',', ' ' };
byte A, R, G, B;
string color = @"Color [A=255, R=245, G=243, B=244]";

byte.TryParse((color.Substring(color.IndexOf('A') + 2, 3)).Trim(trimChars), out A);
byte.TryParse((color.Substring(color.IndexOf('R') + 2, 3)).Trim(trimChars), out R);
byte.TryParse((color.Substring(color.IndexOf('G') + 2, 3)).Trim(trimChars), out G);
byte.TryParse((color.Substring(color.IndexOf('B') + 2, 3)).Trim(trimChars), out B);

Color newColor = Color.FromArgb(A,R,G,B);
```